# Unexpected type + non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context errors?

Tags: java

My code does not compile.  How can I resolve the errors?

```
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount{
private double balance;

public BankAccount(double b) {
    balance = b;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double d){
    balance += d;
}

public boolean withdraw(double d){
    if(d > balance){
        return false;
    } else {
        balance -= d;
        return true;
    }
}
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount{
    private double interest;
    public SavingsAccount(double k, double inRate){
        super(k);
        interest = inRate;
    }

    public void gainInterest(){
        super.getBalance() = super.getBalance() * interest;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(1000, .05);
    test.gainInterest();
    System.out.println(test.getBalance());

}
```

The following errors are

> I get the unexpected type error at
>       **super.getBalance() = super.getBalance() * interest;** and the "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" at **SavingsAccount test = new SavingsAccount(1000, .05);**

Comment: What do you think `super.getBalance() = ...` does?

Comment: note: never do this in a real bank. [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a value to a method.

You will need to assign the result to a variable or pass the result to another method, in this case you can use `deposit`, something like...

```
public void gainInterest(){
    deposit(super.getBalance() * interest);
}
```